# I can't add a new extension

Tags: magento-1.7, debugging

Since few days I can't add any extension by manager.
Below, you can see examples with GTSpeed & fooman speedster extensions.
This is the error message in exception.log :

```
2014-07-21T06:52:53+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Type de bloc non valide : Fooman_Speedster_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Head' in /home/XXXXx/www/store/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27333): Mage::throwException('Type de bloc no...')
#1 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27275): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('adminhtml/page_...', Array)
#2 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27310): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/page_...', 'head')
#3 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27077): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/page_...', 'head')
#4 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27043): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27044): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(13507): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(13432): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#9 /home/XXXXx/www/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#10 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(13582): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#11 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(17927): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(17484): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(20061): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/XXXXx/www/store/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/XXXXx/www/store/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
2014-07-21T06:54:22+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Type de bloc non valide : GT_Speed_Block_Page_Html_Head' in /home/XXXXx/www/store/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27333): Mage::throwException('Type de bloc no...')
#1 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27275): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('page/html_head', Array)
#2 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27310): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/html_head', 'head')
#3 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27077): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/html_head', 'head')
#4 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27043): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(27044): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(13507): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(146): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/XXXXx/www/store/app/code/community/Simtech/Searchanise/controllers/CategoryController.php(68): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#9 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(13582): Simtech_Searchanise_CategoryController->viewAction()
#10 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(17927): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#11 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(17484): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/__default.php(20061): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /home/XXXXx/www/store/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/XXXXx/www/store/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

And this is in system.log :

```
2014-07-21T06:54:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/GT_Speed_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
2014-07-21T06:54:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/GT_Speed_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src:.:/usr/local/php5.4/lib/php')  in /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
2014-07-21T06:55:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Product.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
2014-07-21T06:55:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Product.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src:.:/usr/local/php5.4/lib/php')  in /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
2014-07-21T06:56:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config_Grid.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
2014-07-21T06:56:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config_Grid.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src:.:/usr/local/php5.4/lib/php')  in /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
2014-07-21T06:56:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Product.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
2014-07-21T06:56:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Product.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src:.:/usr/local/php5.4/lib/php')  in /home/XXXXx/www/store/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
```

My cache is deactivated.  Compilation is activated (but when I want to deactivated it, my website became white, and I had needs to restore it)

Do you have some ideas about this bug ?

Thanks:)

Comment: Welcome to Magento! Please check this [great debugging tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429) and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you have a few errors, and when you disable compilation they shut down Magento.

As a starting point, try to disable extensions `GT_Speed` and `Fooman_Speedster` in the XML files. They are in the `/app/eta/modules/` folder.

Then clear the cache and re-compile sources.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. I already disabled these extensions by manager. When I tried to disable compilation, my website is blank. So I can't deactivate it

Comment: Clear the cache after these changes and you should see things come back to life?

Comment: To disable or enable compilation manually, do so in the file config.php located in the includes folder just above root level. Put a hash sign in front of define to disable, remove to enable.

Comment: when I clear my cache and add hash on config.php I still have a blank page

Comment: I found why I get blank page : <b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Varien_Image' not found in <b>/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php</b> on line <b>380</b><br />
But I don't know how to fix it

Comment: You can get the file from the magento default installation I think.